# sections in bootstrap colliding with each other

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, sections

i a have a website done in bootstrap, the url is [enter link description here](https://modelsworld.vblp.co.in/)

i am having alignment issues in homepage,most of the sections are colliding with each other, i had to do like below to make those section stop colliding:

```html
<section class="ds gallery-3 s-py-70 s-py-lg-100 s-py-xl-150" id="chinnu1" style="margin-top:80%">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
        <h4 class="big-title" style="text-align:center">
          OUR SERVICES
        </h4>
      </div>
```

to all sections i gave margin-top so that they are not collided, now the issue is after few days again this collision happens and i have to adjust this margin-top again, can anyone please tell me how to fix this permanently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a deep look on your website. Your problem is not the margin. It's the owl carousels. Their position is absolute so they goes over other elements

```
    section.carousel-section .container-fluid {
        overflow: hidden;
        position: absolute;
    }
```

This should be position:relative;